# Creating multiple trunk ports on a Cisco ME3400

Tags: cisco, switch, ethernet, vlan, cisco-commands

I have a cisco ME 3400 switch . And I have configured fa0/23 as trunk port and connected this to a router for carrying multiple vlan traffic. And i have created some vlans eg: 1500, 1501 etc and added each individual ports fa0/1 ,0/2 etc in to separate vlans as access port. Now I can communicate with the server..

Now  I want to connect another switch to this cisco me 3400 . this is for carrying multiple vlan traffic which is created in the cisco me 3400 switch i.e traffic of vlan 1500 , 1501 etc  to another switch.  How to configure this?

Comment: Hello, if you understand you correctly you want to just connect two switches and both switches should have the same VLANs? If so you would just configure the connecting ports on both switches as trunk and be done...

Comment: Please consider adding a diagram with port annotations to describe exactly what you want, because it's a bit unclear.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for "automatic" propagation of your vlans to second switch - this is not possible with ME3400. ME3400 is a Metro Ethernet switch and so does not have *very enterprise-grade* feature called VTP (Vlan Trunk Protocol). You still can connect two switches with the trunk, but you need to create vlans manually on both switches (and these have to match on both sides).